# Error while running fuzzywuzzy/fuzz.py

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have a program that uses **fuzzywuzzy** to match to csvs and find any strings that might be duplicates or very similar. When I compare my two files, **fuzzywuzzy** raises the following error:

```
WARNING:root:Applied processor reduces input query to empty string all comparisons will have score 0. [Query:'+']
```

Anyone have any idea what cause that error to come up?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from process.extractOne().

Fuzzywuzzy does some cleaning of the queries you give it, including case folding and replacing non-letters and non-numbers with white space.

Your query only contains a plus sign, which is replaced by white space, leaving an empty string, which cannot be fuzzy matched against. That causes the error.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this warning? It's annoying when going over a large number of words

Comment: I would like to know that too.

Comment: this is appearing on process.extract too. Id like to know how to suppress error as well